# Is the closure on the Array.every function Asyncous or Synchronous

Tags: node.js, jscript

With reference to the example given in the Array.Every function.  Is the callback asynchronous or synchronous.  The example is:

```
function isBelowThreshold(currentValue) {
  return currentValue < 40;
}

var array1 = [1, 30, 39, 29, 10, 13];

console.log(array1.every(isBelowThreshold));
```

A real world example would be to use the every function to check that all characters are numeric in a test function used in Yup.

Is the callback always a functional synchronous closure, or an asynchronous call back? With reference to the example above.

Comment: node uses jscript or javascript?

Comment: It uses jscript

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's synchronous. There is no callback in the signature for .every() which is usually your first sign that it's asynchronous.  But there's an easy way to test it.  Put a console.log("inside") statement inside your "isBelowThreshold" function, and  console.log("outside") immediately after the array1.every(...).  If it's asynchronous, you'll see "outside" appear either before or interspersed between the "inside" lines.  If it's synchronous, "outside" will appear after everything else.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you CodeMonkey for your suggestion.  I created a test file, as follows:

```
console.log('s1');

function isBelowThreshold(currentValue) {
    console.log('s4');
  return currentValue < 40;
}

console.log('s2');
var array1 = [1, 30, 39, 29, 10, 13];

console.log('s3');
console.log(array1.every(isBelowThreshold));
console.log('s5');
```

Using Node, I tested the script as follows:

[image]

The observable behaviour of the Array Every function is that it is synchronous. The [Array.Prototype.Every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function gives a good description about the "callback".

What then does the term "callback" mean?  Is a simple functional closure, or is it more than that within the context of Jscript?